# Log http requests made BY Apache/PHP Server?

Tags: php, apache, http, curl, server

I've inherited a PHP7/Apache 2.4 site that makes numerous cURL requests to an external API. I have to convert them to another platform (python based), and I'd like to know exactly what HTTP requests the current site is making.

It's not as simple as just examining the PHP curl code, because it's being called from all over this LARGE application with numerous, various configuration options.

I can try tcpdump or Wireshark, but they are complicated; I have complete control over my local dev server, Apache & PHP configuration. I wonder if there is any way to configure the server to log the requests it MAKES?

Comment: `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` should tell you what you need assuming $ch is `$ch = curl_init();`

Answer (score 0):

Tcpdump is probably going to be your best option. Here's a Serverfault answer that has some examples that might help with the actual task of logging the calls:

https://serverfault.com/questions/307626/how-to-log-outgoing-http-requests-from-php-curl

However, I'm not sure how that will solve the problem with your project. You can't guarantee that every curl will be hit by just watching traffic while you use the app. What I'd do in that situation is find each instance of `curl_init()` and then work backward. Something like `> grep -rn --include \*.php --exclude-dir vendor curl_init .`

This grep find all .php files containing `curl_init()` excluding vendor (assuming the project uses composer). And returns the filename and line number.